# Getting per-directory git commit stats

Tags: git

I am trying to get some statistics to measure sub-projects (basically, subdirs) that have received more changes between releases. In my case, I am interested in the Linux Kernel, but that's not important.

I am interested in several metrics, such as changed lines and number of commits. It seems I can do the former with git-diff dirstats. It's not perfect, but it's easy and gives some results:

```
git diff v4.14..v4.18 --dirstat=4,cumulative -- drivers/media
   4.4% drivers/media/dvb-core/
   7.7% drivers/media/dvb-frontends/cxd2880/
  16.9% drivers/media/dvb-frontends/
  16.3% drivers/media/i2c/
   8.2% drivers/media/pci/zoran/
  18.9% drivers/media/pci/
  16.6% drivers/media/platform/
   5.5% drivers/media/rc/
  12.4% drivers/media/usb/
   4.0% drivers/media/v4l2-core/
 100.0% drivers/media/
```

However, I have found no out-of-the-box (i.e. without bash scripting) solution to do this for the commit count metric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a script indeed.

[`git log` does have the same `dirstat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---dirstatltparam1param282308203gt), but that simply display the same data you already see with `git diff`.